# Animate Loading of an Image view is Repeating

Tags: android, animation

I'm using an adapter view for for a list view to retrieve " Publications " from Parse.com, I'm using an animation for loading image from Parse. and i'm using another function to get a circle view of the image.

all is working great, the loading is perfect but when I slide down/up on the list view the image is animated again each time I slide Up/Down. and I couldn't stop that.

here is the code of my adapter :

```js
public class adapterview extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {
 Bitmap image;
    public adapterview(Context context, ArrayList<Message> Messages) {
       super(context, 0, Messages);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Get the data item for this position
       final Message m = getItem(position);    
       // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
       if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom2, parent, false);
       }
     
       TextView message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
       TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
       TextView user = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user);
       message.setText(m.getMessage());
       user.setText(m.getUser()); 
       new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
       .execute(m.getImage());

       return convertView;
   }
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
     ImageView bmImage;

     public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
         this.bmImage = bmImage;
     }

     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
         String urldisplay = urls[0];
         Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
         try {
           InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
           mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return mIcon11;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{
            new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent),
            new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), getCircleBitmap(result))
    });

    
         bmImage.setImageDrawable(td);
         td.startTransition(2000);
     }
   }
   
    private Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
     final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
      bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

     final int color = Color.RED;
     final Paint paint = new Paint();
     final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
     final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

     paint.setAntiAlias(true);
     canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
     paint.setColor(color);
     canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

     paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
     canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

     bitmap.recycle();

     return output;
    }
}
```

if you need any other information you think could be helpful for you to determine the problem just let me know

Answer (score 0):

When a list needs to display a item it calls its Adapters getView() function.  When you scroll and list items are no longer visible they are release and not kept in memory.

When scrolling every list item has DownloadImageTask() executed each time it becomes visible.  The downloaded image from function is stored only in the ImageView of list item, so is it released from memory as soon as you scroll the list item.

The solution is to store the downloaded image then in getView() function assign the image into the ImageView.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I take the TransitialDrawable animation, it works, and I use a huge database, so if I should store all the downloaded images, it would be useless

Comment: Your goal is to stop the animation from repeating when the user scrolls the list up and down, is this correct?  If so, the reason the animation repeats when the view is scrolled is that the ImageView is recreated each time it becomes visible.  After the image has been downloaded you are calling startTransition() which is causing the animation.

Comment: Yeah that's right I want to stop the animation from repeating, so how can I stop the animation repeat ?

Comment: The animation will occur every time startTransition() is called.  If you add a log statement before this call in your code you should see that it is being called for each item in the list every time the item becomes visible.  To prevent the animation from happening multiple times you can save the downloaded images to an image cache so they don't need to be downloaded each time, or keep track of those that you have already animated and only call the startTranisition() function the first time the image is downloaded.